# Java cooperating generic classes: can we avoid unchecked cast?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I have two abstract generic classes. They cooperate and hence depend on each other. Occasionally one needs to pass `this` to the other. I am trying to find a type safe way to do that.

```
public abstract class AbstractA<T extends AbstractB<? extends AbstractA<T>>> {

    protected void foo() {
        T aB = createB();
        aB.setA(this);
    }

    /** factory method */
    abstract public T createB();
    
}

public abstract class AbstractB<T extends AbstractA<? extends AbstractB<T>>> {

    private T theA;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setA(AbstractA<? extends AbstractB<?>> theA) { // dreamed of parameter list (T theA)
        // Unchecked cast from AbstractA<capture#1-of ? extends AbstractB<?>> to T
        this.theA = (T) theA;
    }
    
    protected T getA() {
        return theA;
    }
    
}
```

My question is whether I can find a cleaner way so I avoid the unchecked cast in `AbstractB.setA()`. I had hoped to declare it `setA(T theA)`, but then the call to it won’t compile: The method setA(capture#1-of ? extends AbstractA<T>) in the type AbstractB<capture#1-of ? extends AbstractA<T>> is not applicable for the arguments (AbstractA<T>). I am still struggling to understand whether the compiler should know enough to allow it or not.

I was thinking my problem may be related to the one discussed in [Java generics compilation error - The method method(Class<capture#1-of ? extends Interface>) in the type <type> is not applicable for the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021900/java-generics-compilation-error-the-method-methodclasscapture1-of-extends). My unchecked cast was inspired from there. I liked the reply by Tom Hawtin - tackling, but I have not found a way to apply it to my situation.

My user will declare concrete subclasses and instantiate one `ConcreteA` and any number of `ConcreteB`s:

```
public class ConcreteA extends AbstractA<ConcreteB> {

    @Override
    public ConcreteB createB() {
        return new ConcreteB();
    }
    
    public void concreteAMethod() {
        // ...
    }
    
}

public class ConcreteB extends AbstractB<ConcreteA> {

    public void bar() {
        ConcreteA a = getA();
        a.concreteAMethod();
    }
    
}
```

(`class AbstractA<T extends AbstractB<? extends AbstractA<T>>>` looks a bit complicated; I thought I needed it for concrete subclasses to know each other’s exact types, but apparently it doesn’t give me that.)

Comment: "looks a bit complicated" - indeed. I wonder whether this nesting is really necessary (or reasonably beneficial) for the application case. Omitting the last `extends` already solves the problem, but as long as it is not clear where this genericity is actually *required*, one can not say whether this applicable in your case.

Comment: You’re right, as the code in the question stands, parameterization of `AbstractA` is superfluous, and therefore `AbstractB<T extends AbstractA>` is enough.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this question has been DVed heavily. IMHO, this question is clear, focused and has all the necessary elements to classify it as a good question. It will be useful for future visitors if one of the DVers can explain the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to realize that my problem really came out of stuffing two concepts into the AbstractA/ConcreteA hierarchy that didn’t belong together. Though maybe not interesting to very many, I am posting this insight for two reasons: (1) I feel I owe Chris Wohlert the answer I have found myself (2) more importantly, I’d love to inspire anyone else facing a similar tricky generics issue to review your design from a higher level than just solving the generics and/or class cast issue. It certainly helped me. The cast/generics problem was a sign that something more fundamental was not quite right.

```
public abstract class AbstractA {

    public void foo() {
        AbstractB aB = createB();
        aB.setA(this);
    }

    /** factory method */
    abstract public AbstractB createB();

}

public abstract class AbstractB {

    private AbstractA theA;

    public void setA(AbstractA theA) {
        this.theA = theA;
    }

    // methods that use theA

}
```

No generics and no class cast. Taking out the stuff that didn’t belong in the A class hierarchy into ConcreteC (with no AbstractC):

```
public class Client {

    public void putTheActTogether() {
        ConcreteC theC = new ConcreteC();

        // the concrete A
        AbstractA theA = new AbstractA() {
            @Override
            public AbstractB createB() {
                return new ConcreteB(theC);
            }
        };
        // call methods in theA
    }

}

public class ConcreteB extends AbstractB {

    private final ConcreteC c;

    public ConcreteB(ConcreteC c) {
        super();
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void bar() {
        c.concreteCMethod();
    }

}

public class ConcreteC {

    public void concreteCMethod() { // was concreteAMethod(); moved and renamed
        // ...
    }

}
```

The client needs a few more lines than before. In my real-world code I needed to duplicate one final field in AbstractA and ConcreteC, but it made sense to do. All in all I consider it a low price for a design that is otherwise pure and simple.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, this should create the binding you want.

```
class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteA a = new ConcreteA();
        ConcreteB b = new ConcreteB();
        a.foo(b);
        b = (ConcreteB) a.getB();
    }
}

abstract class AbstractA<T extends AbstractB<?>>{

    private AbstractB<?> b;

    public AbstractB<?> getB(){
        return b;
    }

    void foo(AbstractB<?> aB) {
        b = aB;
        aB.bar(this);
    }
}

abstract class AbstractB<T extends AbstractA<?>> {

    private AbstractA<?> a;

    public AbstractA<?> getA(){
        return a;
    }

    public void bar(AbstractA<?> theA) {
        a = theA;
        theA.foo(this);
    }
}

class ConcreteA extends AbstractA<ConcreteB>{

}

class ConcreteB extends AbstractB<ConcreteA>{

}
```

I think this is what you ended up at yourself. I am not able to remove the cast to ConcreteB, getB() simply cannot be sure of the type it is holding. I now see why you had multiple generic statements in your declaration. :)

If you're up for it, continue searching, and post your own answer if you find one, I'd love to see it.

I hope solving half your problem counts for anything. ;)

Comment: Looks nice, thank you very much.
You’ve solved at least half of my problem. In `bar()` I’m happy with seeing `theA` as an `AbstractA`. The other half (I realize I didn’t tell you) is I want to store `theA` in a field and provide a getter for `ConcreteB` to get it. It wants a `ConcreteA`, which the cast in my workaround produced. I can do the same cast in your code. Can I avoid it altogether?
A detail, my Eclipse prefers `abstract class AbstractA<T extends AbstractB<?>>`, it stops it from complaining about using the raw class.

Comment: I will look into it, and update the answer when I have one. :) Yeah, edited the answer to reflect that Eclipse warning.

Comment: Thank you for looking into my problem so kindly. While I was, of course, perfectly clear in my mind about my intention, I more and more tend to think you’re right, `getB()` cannot know exactly which type it is dealing with, so the unchecked cast is necessary.

Comment: But you're completely not using the generic type arguments here at all. Neither `AbstractA` nor `AbstractB` uses `T` in its code; you're effectively using them as non-generic types (by always using wildcard types). If you removed all the brackets, it would compile the same.

Comment: @newacct I surpose you're right, honestly though, then remove the generics. A cast will obviously still be needed. If I recall correctly, the first version did use the generics. I've seen your answer, and it looks good, a valid solution even though OP gave up :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it now why I cannot declare `public void setA(T theA)` in `AbstractB` and then call it as `aB.setA(this)` in `foo()`. Suppose we had:

```
class IntermediateConcreteA extends AbstractA<ConcreteB> {

    @Override
    public ConcreteB createB() {
        return new ConcreteB();
    }

}

class SubConcreteA1 extends IntermediateConcreteA {}

class SubConcreteA2 extends IntermediateConcreteA {}

class ConcreteB extends AbstractB<SubConcreteA2> {}
```

Now if I have a `SubConcreteA1` and call its `foo()`, then `createB()` will return an object that can pass as an `AbstractB<SubConcreteA2>` but cannot pass as an `AbstractB<SubConcreteA1>`. Therefore its `setA()` shouldn’t accept `this` as an argument. The compiler error message is logical after all.

Answer (score 0):

Each abstract class would be parameterized with two type parameters, one for the actual concrete class of A, and one for the actual concrete class of B:

```
public abstract class AbstractA<A extends AbstractA<A,B>, B extends AbstractB<A,B>> {

    protected void foo() {
        B aB = createB();
        aB.setA(getThis());
    }

    abstract public A getThis();
    abstract public B createB();

}

public abstract class AbstractB<A extends AbstractA<A,B>, B extends AbstractB<A,B>> {

    private A theA;

    public void setA(A theA) {
        this.theA = theA;
    }

    protected A getA() {
        return theA;
    }

}

public class ConcreteA extends AbstractA<ConcreteA, ConcreteB> {

    @Override
    public ConcreteA getThis() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ConcreteB createB() {
        return new ConcreteB();
    }

    public void concreteAMethod() {
        // ...
    }

}

public class ConcreteB extends AbstractB<ConcreteA, ConcreteB> {

    public void bar() {
        ConcreteA a = getA();
        a.concreteAMethod();
    }

}
```

Comment: aB.setA(this); gives me "The method setA(A) in the type AbstractB<A,B> is not applicable for the arguments (AbstractA<A,B>)" when I paste your code into eclipse, did you not get this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It sounds like a good idea. I too get "The method setA(A) in the type AbstractB<A,B> is not applicable for the arguments (AbstractA<A,B>)". I am using Java 8 and Eclipse Luna.

Comment: @OleV.V.: Oops. I forgot that there's a `this` in there.

Comment: That’s to the point: If in `AbstractA` I can have type safe access to the concrete type of `this`, I can solve the rest. Thanks for making this crystal clear. In your solution, a dishonest subclass could return a different object then `this`, but the superclass can easily check that.

Comment: @OleV.V.: It is not "dishonest" if it returns a different type, if that type was used as its type argument, because then it's declared to return that type.

Answer (score 0):

A factory can solve it:

```
public abstract class AbstractA {

    public void abstractAMethod() {
        // ...
    }

}

public abstract class AbstractB<A> {

    private A theA;

    public void setA(A theA) {
        this.theA = theA;
    }

    protected A getA() {
        return theA;
    }

}

public abstract class AbstractFactory<A extends AbstractA, B extends AbstractB<A>> {

    private A theA = createA();

    public A getA() {
        return theA ;
    }

    public B getNextB() {
        B newB = createB();
        newB.setA(theA);
        return newB;
    }

    protected abstract A createA();
    protected abstract B createB();
}
```

Now the user can go:

```
public class ConcreteA extends AbstractA {

    public void concreteAMethod() {
        // ...
    }

}

public class ConcreteB extends AbstractB<ConcreteA> {

    public void bar() {
        ConcreteA a = getA();
        a.abstractAMethod();
        a.concreteAMethod();
    }

}

public class ConcreteFactory extends AbstractFactory<ConcreteA, ConcreteB> {

    @Override
    protected ConcreteA createA() {
        return new ConcreteA();
    }

    @Override
    protected ConcreteB createB() {
        return new ConcreteB();
    }

}
```

I don’t think it’s a typical application of the abstract factory pattern, though …

@Chris Wohlert, I did give up in my production code since I considered the factory overkill, but I could not let go of the theoretical question.