# Compare current date with date from MySQL DB using Java

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

I have a MySQL database with several columns including one with expiry date. I am using the type 'sql.date' or MySQL's `date` type.

Now according to the business logic, I am trying to figure out two things-

1. how many days are left for the expiry of the product and
2. whether the product has already expired.

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```

I can procure the current date using this, but I am not able to compare it with the expiry date using the query given below.

```
rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Checkout where expiry_date <= date ");
```

I also tried to replace the `date` variable with the SQL methods `now()` and `curdate()` but to no avail.

I am new to the JAVA field, so please help. If additional information is required, I would be happy to furnish it.

**Edit**

Also tried this one out -

```
long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();  
java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(millis);  

ResultSet rs2 = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Checkout where expiry_date < ?;");
stmt.setDate(1, date);
rs2 = stmt.executeQuery();
```

But still it is not working.

Out of the top 50 fifty suggestions I could not solve the issue.

Comment: is server time/timezones different from the java location. `SELECT NOW()` and see what you get compared to the java implementation.

Comment: I got this `2020-05-15 13:09:45` by executing `Select now()` which is the same as my machine time. `curdate()` is more helpful to me in this case as I require only the date.

Comment: I also tried out - `java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
                            
                            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
                            stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Checkout where expiry_date < ?");
                            stmt.setDate(1, date);
                            rs2 = stmt.executeQuery();`

Comment: I did this with expiry_date being the BIGINT data type in the mysql table and comparing it to the long value of Calender#getInstance()#getTime()#getTime()

Comment: @CureMe can you provide me with a little bit of code, so that I can understand it properly?

Comment: @Chris I added a full answer to explain my concept.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It’s a poor question, I downvoted. I can’t believe your search didn’t turn up a million suggestions, or close. Please report in the question. You also forgot to tell us the datatype of the column in MySQL, it’s essential.

Comment: Admitted, @Chris, it takes a bit to learn how to ask a good question. [My own first questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013179/java-cooperating-generic-classes-can-we-avoid-unchecked-cast) were downvoted more heavily than this one of yours. Next time, if you report at least a couple of those top 50 suggestions and in what way they didn’t work, we can help you better, guide you much more precisely. And thanks for reporting back on my comment and vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the correct MySQL datatype and statement.
As I mention in a comment, I recommend using the BIGINT datatype of the `expiry_date` column.
In your program, you will want to do the following:

```
long currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Checkout where expiry_date < ?");
stmt.setLong(1, currentTime);
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery();
```

This compares the value in the database, which should look something like `1589522424053` to the value of the currentTime variable, which should look something like `1589532467163`.

Comment: so I basically need to edit the structure of my table and change the column to datatype BIGINT from Date ? If so, it would mess up a lot of the work up till now, as the table is used from various sources.

Comment: @Chris Sadly that is what this solution involves, I would recommend using a script to either copy everything to another table or use the MySQL alter command to alter the date column in the table.

Comment: Thanks I changed it and got the correct result. One more question that I have is how can I get the difference between these dates, if for example one is expired and the other is the current date.

Comment: @Chris I believe to get the difference in seconds you could do this: `int diffInSecs = (int)((currentTime - rs2.getLong("expiry_date")) / 1000)`. You can then just divide this value by 60 to get minutes etc.